# function return the same value

Tags: javascript

```
N_ALPHA = 6;
N_CHOICES = 4;
ALPHABET = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
var alphabet = ALPHABET.substring(0, N_ALPHA);
var indexForm=new Array();
function guessStrToArr(inStr)
{ 
  {
    for (i=0;i<N_CHOICES;i++)
    {
       indexForm[i]=alphabet.indexOf(inStr.charAt(i).toUpperCase());
    }
  }
 return indexForm;
}

function numBulls(guess, goal)
{
  guess=new Array (guessStrToArr(prompt('enter your guess1')));
  alert(guess);
  goal=new Array(guessStrToArr(prompt('enter your guess2')));
  var checkArray = new Array (guess.concat(goal); 
  alert(checkArray);

  var count=0;

  for (i=0;i<N_CHOICES;i++)
  {
    if (guess[i]===goal[i])
    {
      count++
    }
  }
  return count;
}

numBulls();
```

when I run the above code, it returnt the same array, evern I type different code into prompt alet box. I don't know why, can you please help me?
Thank you very much.

Comment: Any pointers on what your code is supposed to do?

Comment: Post `promt()` function?

Comment: This code has syntax errors. There is a missing `)` before the `alert(checkArray)`. fix up your indentation and there may be more problems popping up. Maybe an extra `{` at `function guessStrToArr()`

Comment: After fixing the missing `)`, it prompts me twice and I enter `abc` then `def` and I get as output two different things. Hard to know what you intend as the output though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`indexForm` is a global variable. When you call the `guessStrToArr` function for the first time array gets populated. The second time it gets repopulated. When you're doing the comparison, your comparing the array against itself. Try this:

```
function guessStrToArr(inStr) { 
    var indexForm = new Array();

    for (i = 0; i < N_CHOICES; i++) {
       indexForm[i] = alphabet.indexOf(inStr.charAt(i).toUpperCase());
    }

    return indexForm;
}
```

Also note that you are making no attempt to ensure that `inStr.length` is the same as `N_CHOICES`.

Comment: Hi Flem, you are great help. you saved me from another 10 hours frustration. You really help me greatly. Thank you so much.